# Use JavaFx Media Player as default player for media files

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing Media Player in `JavaFx` and now I want that when I right click on any media `(.mp4)` file and open with my JAR file that it will start playing. How to get this function work?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but my instinct tells me to possibly research what happens when you open an `.mp4` using the `open with...` option from the right click menu. I would imagine that it uses the file as a command line input, and goes from there. I could be completely off base here though, best to check it out.

Comment: On `Windows`  you can use a batch file which is accepting the path of the selected file.Then you try open with and you select that batch file.The batch file is calling the jar file and passing as parameters the path of the selected file.I have done this in the past although i would also like to see something different using the registry so i upvote this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro in java, but in most programming languages when we ***open with*** something, the path is sent as argument.
In java maybe the parameter `String[] args`in main method, which is an array, will contain the path to the file you opened with. Then you can use it to open  the file.

You can test it easily by printing the array `args`, and opening the mp4 file with .exe or .jar(not sure)
At end sorry for the confusion but I am at this time unable to test as i am away from any jvm.

If you want it in android then you have to further view intents-filters here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: Else if you want to go with batch file method as stated by @ GOXR3PLUS, it will be easy but then also you need to handle arguments recieved by the application.